# the strings are rusty and the mitt is dusty -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Sams Teach Yourself Apache 2 in 24 Hours](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Sams_Teach_Yourself_Apache_2_in_24_Hours.html?id=cnDuw7GV4uYC&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> Ian Kallen is a senior software engineer and product team lead with Covalent
>   Technologies developing enterprise-class management tools for the Apache Web server. Prior to joining Covalent, Ian managed the software and network operations at Salon.com and GameSpot.com. Ian is an instructor at San Francisco State University’s Multimedia Studies program, and has been an invited speaker at the O’Reilly Open Source Convention, ApacheCon, and other technology events. In his spare time, Ian plays blues guitar and softball, but he hasn’t had any spare time, so **the strings are rusty and the mitt is dusty**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This phrase is about the "blues guitar and softball" earlier in the same sentence. The writer wants you to imagine the tools used in playing guitar or playing softball are not in a good state because they have not been used in a long time. Instead of saying "he hasn't touched the guitar in a long time", it says "the [guitar] strings are rusty". Instead of saying "he hasn't played softball in a long time", it says "the [softball] mitt is dusty". The writer is trying to be clever because he is doing two things at once:

1. using this common technique of having small details be an example of a bigger situation, and
2. describing these small details with words that rhyme.

Comment: It is perhaps worth adding that this is not an idiom, and that without the previous line hardly anybody would have any idea what this was about.